# Best way to increment the date in a String URL?

Tags: java, string, parsing

So I have a URL that contains `date=2016-01-25` somewhere in between. My goal is, when a user enters the URL and n days (in a GUI application's text fields), it should go into a loop of n times and increment the date from the URL. That also means it goes to the next month if it is 30/31. Anyone have an optimized approach to this?

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Are you asking how to increment a date day-after-day for a certain number of days? What does that have to do with URLs? The key to a successful Question on StackOverflow is to be narrowly focused. Please edit your Question to clarify and strip away the extraneous details.

Comment: You can forget about the fact that it is a URL. All I need is the URL in String format to increment the date for the specified number of days because the URL executes a certain javascript function for that date within the URL. So if I can loop through the same URL and just increment the dates, I can execute the javascript function for each day rather than  manually clicking "next" and then clicking on a button in the web page that executes the function.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706) and many others.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java 8, you can use the java.time.LocalDate class to parse, add days, and convert back to a string. Here's an example:

```
String date = "2016-01-25";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
localDate = localDate.plusDays(15);
System.out.println(localDate); // Prints "2016-02-09"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the Java 8 solutions, if you're using an earlier version of Java you can use JodaTime's LocalDate class to accomplish the same thing. Syntax will be the same as in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse the date string out of the URL, using something like regex and then create a Date object increment your date and rebuild the URL.

Java's Date primitives such as [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) have support for "plusDays(int n)"